# Get swap memory info where swapinfo not available

Tags: swap, hp-ux

I have HP-UX box. I need to write shell script to see the swap memory. Unfortunately. The box don't have swapinfo command. Is there any alternative way to see the swap usage percentage?

Please note that here we are not allowed to install any thing.

Comment: What version of HP-UX is it?

Answer (score 1):

While you will get different figures (due to the intended usage), you may find the summary lines from [`top`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/top.1.html) useful, since it shows the total real and virtual memory along with the amount of memory used:

```
      Memory Data
            Includes virtual and real memory in use (with the amount of
            memory considered "active" in parentheses) and the amount of
            free memory.
```

Also, [`vmstat`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/vmstat.1.html) can give useful information:

```
       memory      Information about the usage of virtual and real
                   memory.  Virtual pages are considered active if they
                   belong to processes that are running or have run in
                   the last 20 seconds.

                        avm     Active virtual pages

                        free    Size of the free list
```

Further reading:

- [swap (paging )space in HP Unix.....](http://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/swap-paging-space-in-HP-Unix/td-p/4771178)

Comment: vmstat available. But couldn't identify the swap percentage.

Answer (score -1):

The exact command for swapping is `swapon` and switch `s` ( like this`swapon -s` ) will help you to get swap space.
Also `free -tm` will helps you.

Comment: On HP-UX, really?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that